# ThreadLocal issue

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

ThreadLocal provide an exclusive copy of the wrapped object to the thread.
I am executing a scenario

```
public class CustomerThread extends Thread{

static Integer custId =0;
private static ThreadLocal t1 = new ThreadLocal(){
    protected Integer initialValue() {
        return ++custId;        
    }
};

public CustomerThread(String name) {
   super(name);
}

@Override
public void run() {
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " executing with customer Id : "+t1.get());
}

}

public class ThreadLocalDemo {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomerThread c1 = new CustomerThread("A");
    CustomerThread c2 = new CustomerThread("B");
    CustomerThread c3 = new CustomerThread("C");
    CustomerThread c4 = new CustomerThread("D");
    CustomerThread c5 = new CustomerThread("E");
    CustomerThread c6 = new CustomerThread("F");
    CustomerThread c7 = new CustomerThread("G");
    CustomerThread c8 = new CustomerThread("H");
    CustomerThread c9 = new CustomerThread("I");
    CustomerThread c10 = new CustomerThread("J");
    c1.start();
    c2.start();
    c3.start();
    c4.start();
    c5.start();
    c6.start();
    c7.start();
    c8.start();
    c9.start();
    c10.start();
}

}
```

**Threadlocal should get unique value for each customer but when i am runing above scenario some times it is producing**

A executing with customer Id : 1

B executing with customer Id : 1

D executing with customer Id : 3

C executing with customer Id : 2

E executing with customer Id : 4

F executing with customer Id : 5

G executing with customer Id : 6

H executing with customer Id : 7

I executing with customer Id : 8

J executing with customer Id : 9

here A and B getting same value.

can someone explain is this right behaviour w.r.t ThreadLocal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `ThreadLocal`.  Your problem is that this is not an atomic operation:

```
++custID;
```

What can happen is, thread A sees `custID == 1`, stores that into its own bin in the `ThreadLocal` objet, and assigns `custID=2`.  Meanwhile, thread B also sees `custID == 1` and it does the same thing.

You need some kind of protection--a mutex lock, or an `AtomicInteger`, to insure that only one thread at a time tries to obtain a new `custID` value.

---

P.S.: I would try to avoid `ThreadLocal` in new code.  The main use of `ThreadLocal` is in converting old code that uses `static` variables from single-threaded to multi-threaded.  But if you're writing new code, you should be doing your best to avoid `static` in the first place. `static` makes your code difficult to maintain, and *very* difficult to properly test.

There's nothing wrong with using `static` in small, throwaway programs except that it'll teach you a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `AtomicInteger` for your counter.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html